# Looking for an appropriate design pattern to implement on a single thread mechanism

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have on my WebSite application a third party payment solution. Like paypal for example.
After the user has payed on the third party site, I need to go on a "server to server" base API and check to see if the deposit succeeded.

What I thought to do is to write to a static singletoned member the event that someone is going out to deposit funds.

I will have a single thread running in the back and check to see if the certain deposit was done.
if succeeded or failed, invoke some method.  After one hour kill the thread if there are no results about the certain user at all.

At the bottom line, the thread needs to run only when I have a deposit request.
And once the result was on the provider server, the thread will be destroyed.

What kind of design pattern is there to implement such an event?
What do you think about this mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are better not to rely on a low-level feature (such as thread creation) to implement your billing features.

The better solution would be to store the entry indicating intention to payment to DB, and have some cron task scheduled to check if the payment has been done.

Also, with Paypal you don't need to check if the payment has been done by yourself; IIRC, you're just sending the synchronous HTTP request to paypal from the server (after the user returned to you from paypal site with all the appropriate tokens), and the response from paypal will contain information on whether the payment succeeded or not. So it is possible to implement paypal integration even without any long-living objects such as DB entry or a system thread.

Comment: It is not paypal, but never the less, 70% of the people going out to a third party deposit are not click on the "return to merchant". I am using c#, what is wrong with having a thread to implementation here? thanks

Comment: My point was that with paypal (at least with their API i have worked with) "return to the merchant" is the required part of the payment process. The control flow was something like: when a customer presses the "checkout" button on your site, they're redirected to Paypal site, where they're prompted for credentials and showed the order description and amount; after authorization, paypal redirects the customer back to your website, where they're given an order confirmation button among other info; when they're pressing this button, your server sends a synchronous request to PayPal,

Comment: which commits the transaction (if possible), responds whether the transaction was successful or not, and you're processing this request synchronously, in the same worker thread you processed the user button press / form submittal.

Comment: As for "_what is wrong with having a thread to implementation here?_" - think for example what will happen if your server is e.g. rebooted during this time, or the IIS service crashes, or you lost a network connectivity for an hour, or something else? With the implementation based on threads, you won't ever get any sign there was some failed attempt of transaction (unless you'll write it in DB as i suggest), and you'll have to deal with a lot of angry customers which have their money debited from their bank accounts but not credited on their account in your service.

Answer (score 0):

If you had another process that periodically checked the payment, then you would have a better separation of concerns.  Let the user post their payment to the 3rd party site and have another process actually doing the processing of the payments.  This process can run periodically at whatever interval is acceptable for your business case.  Assign some sort of unique identifier so you can identify the user and the payment.

There isn't really any benefit for starting a thread to do the checking.  This just leads to more potential problems (think about what would happen if IIS decided to recycle or your data center got flooded?).  These kinds of problems are notoriously difficult to reproduce and can cause hours of lost productivity and headaches, which translates to cost.